# What to use for representing data in graphs in c# and asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have to create simple application. User selects time period and I get data from database for selected period and put it on the graph. How are graphs generated in c#. What library should I use for this?

Comment: Please check [help/on-topic] to see which types of questions are on-topic for StackOverflow. If you have a concrete programming problem we're here to help, but recommendations for 3rd party tools is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can from the tool box drag in a chart control.

eg:

[image]

And you can even use the wizard to setup the data source.

So, the built in chart control is a good start. Perahps there is some reason you don't want to use this asp.net control?

Comment: I started at new job. I am making app for that. This seemed a little ugly and outdated i just wanted nicer graphs. But it is gonna be internally used, so I guess I could use this. I tried plotly, but now I have to pass the data using ajax to client side and have to make controller and also have to pass some data to controller from my webform. I made a mess doing this. Thanks a lot for your help!